# Al usar UseSelector me toma el state de @init y no el dispath

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Cree un dispatch en un componente para cargar los datos del usuario:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const TrearDatos = async () => {
      const DatosJson = JSON.stringify({ id: IdDoc, d: 0 });
      const api = axios.create({ baseURL: URL.servidor });
      const response = await api.post(
        "/api-php-react/admin/Crud_admin.php",
        DatosJson
      );
      const data = response.data;

      dispatch({
        type: "@addDatauser",
        user: data,
      });
      setNombres({
        Nombre: data.Nombre,
        Apellidos: data.Apellido,
        rol: data.rol,
        Tipo: data.Tipo,
      });
    };
    TrearDatos();
  }, [IdDoc, dispatch]);
```

y se graba pero al momento de consultarlo me sale false claro este es el state inicial del redux
@init
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
es decir no me toma el ultimo grabado si no que el primero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte mejor tambien adjunta el codigo de tu redux, saludos